# Lie derivatives of tensor product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

Given a smooth vector field $X = \sum X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that for all $i,j = 1,...,n$.

$$\mathcal{L}_X(d x_i \otimes d x_j) = \sum_{r=1}^{n}(\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x_r} dx_r \otimes dx_k + \frac{\partial X^k}{\partial x_r} dx_j \otimes dx_r)$$

I've looked at the Lie derivative axioms here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) but it hasn't really helped.

Any assistance with this will be great.

Comment: Apply axiom 2 (for tensor products), then axiom 4 (Lie derivative commutes with exterior derivative) and then axiom 1 (Lie derivative of functions), and for axiom 1, recall that if $X = \sum X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ then $X(f) = \sum X^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$, in particular $X(x^j) = X^j$. And finally, recall that for any function $f$, the exterior derivative is $df = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} dx^i$. Also, your quoted formula here is wrong (there's an $i$ on the LHS, but no $i$ on the RHS)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The Lie derivative follows the Leibniz rule for tensors. That is $$L_{X}(S \otimes T) = L_X(S) \otimes T + S\otimes L_X(T)$$ And use Cartan's identity which says that for a one form $\alpha$, you have
$$L_X(\alpha) = i_X(d\alpha) + d(i_{X}\alpha)$$